# Casting shared_ptr to templatized class

Tags: c++, uhd

I am trying to cast a shared pointer to a base class to a shared pointer to a templatized derived class when using a library ([UHD](https://files.ettus.com/manual)).
In particular, I have obtained a shared pointer to the class `filter_info_base` ([here](https://files.ettus.com/manual/classuhd_1_1filter__info__base.html)) and I would like to cast it to a pointer to a `digital_filter_base` class ([here](https://files.ettus.com/manual/classuhd_1_1digital__filter__base.html)), since this would allow me to get the taps of the filter and the other parameters via the proper getters.

I have searched the web for hours, but all the solutions I have obtained were not working. In particular, the answer seems to be "use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`", but if I do

```
uhd::digital_filter_base<int16_t>::sptr p = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<uhd::digital_filter_base<int16_t>>(a_rx_FIR1);
```

(where `a_rx_FIR1` is the sptr to the base class) I get from GCC:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘dynamic_pointer_cast(uhd::filter_info_base::sptr&)’
 uhd::digital_filter_base<int16_t>::sptr p = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<uhd::digital_filter_base<int16_t>>(a_rx_FIR1);
```

Has anyone got an idea about how to do this cast?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

RH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is becouse `uhd::filter_info_base::sptr` is a boost shared pointer:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr< filter_info_base > sptr;
```

And `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` works only for `std::shared_ptr`, you cannot mix them and you need to use [boost version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#dynamic_pointer_cast):

```
uhd::digital_filter_base<int16_t>::sptr p = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<uhd::digital_filter_base<int16_t>>(a_rx_FIR1);
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot, I feel a bit dumb I hadn't tried it :S

Comment: @RH6 so as you are new to SO, please accept my question (click on tick at the left).

Comment: 2 more minutes wait time before I can do that :(